# Set of radio buttons in "Javascript"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a set of three radio buttons connected with a set of three images - i.e. {image1, radioBtn1}, {image2, radioBtn2}, {image3, radioBtn3}.

I'm trying to do the following: When I click on one image, the radio button connected to this button turn to 'checked' automatically (for example: when I click on image3, radioBtn3 will be checked)

I've tried the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="radioBtb1" name="subject"/><a href="#"><img id="image1" src="../image/img3.png" height="150px"/></a>
<input type="radio" id="radioBtb2" name="subject"/><a href="#"><img id="image2" src="../image/img3.png" height="150px"/></a>
<input type="radio" id="radioBtb3" name="subject"/><a href="#"><img id="image3" src="../image/img3.png" height="150px"/></a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function selectSubject(){
    if(document.getElementById('image1'))
        document.getElementById(radioBtb1).checked=true;
    if(document.getElementById('personal'))
        document.getElementById(radioBtb2).checked=true;
    if(document.getElementById('image3'))
        document.getElementById(radioBtb3).checked=true;
}
```

But that didn't work at all.

Comment: Holy formatting... So you want to have 3 buttons, with 3 images, and only the image should change based on you selecting the button?

Comment: It would be easier if you created labels and set a background image on each one as required. Then you wouldn't need any JS.

Comment: radio buttons. When I press on one image, the redio button connected to this image will change to checked.

Comment: No No It wouldn't be easier, cause my web page contains a larg-size images

Comment: `if(document.getElementById('image1'))` – what do you expect that to do? That only checks if an element with that id _exists_ in the document; it has nothing to do with whether that element was clicked or not.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this really easily using the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) tag. Just use the following syntax:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioBtb1" name="subject"/>
    <img id="image1" src="../image/img3.png" height="150px"/>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioBtb2" name="subject"/>
    <img id="image2" src="../image/img3.png" height="150px"/>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioBtb3" name="subject"/>
    <img id="image3" src="../image/img3.png" height="150px"/>
</label>
```

That will automatically do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can also associate a `<label>` to an `<input>` without wrapping them together using the `for` attribute. e.g. In this case, `<label for="radioBtb1">`, since `radioBtb1` is the `id` of the `input`.

Comment: Oh, I'm retarded. Read it backwards.... hahaha. Thought he meant radio button click = image show.

Comment: No, I would show the images continuously at the page, but when I click on one of them then the radio button connected to it will turn to be checked.

Comment: [Accept this answer then :-) I voted up. It'll do exactly what you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/aGG83/) **<-- Example.**

Comment: @lonelyman In case you aren't sure about what Nicholas Hazel meant, he was referring to the checkmark below the points count on the answer. You can mark the answer that was most helpful to you this way, so that it is clear to others who might also be having this same problem what is the best way to do it.

Comment: the radio buttons still unchecked when i click on the image

Comment: @lonelyman you don't need the JavaScript anymore. If you just use this HTML code it will automatically do what you want. See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/aGG83/) Nicholas posted to see what you need for this to work. If this is still not working, please update your question with a new section that shows what the code is you have now.

Comment: Hello agin, Why if I put hyperlink around the images the previous solution didn't work?

Comment: @lonelyman that's because 1) your script never attached the event listener, 2) your `if`-statements didn't test if the *clicked* element was a certain element, but just retrieved the element, and then always checked the box (since retrieving an existing element will always return `true` in an `if`-statement), 3) your element selectors for the radio buttons lack any quotes around the given IDs (it should be `('radioBtb1')` where you have `(radioBtb1)`). In other words, there's a lot wrong with your script that's causing it not to work, but why even bother if there's a really easy `<label>` fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you still wanna do it with javascript you can do like this. I made it so you coukld see everything that happens.

Check [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdbZ6/2/)

```
window.onload = function () {

    var image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
    var image2 = document.getElementById('image2');
    var image3 = document.getElementById('image3');

    image1.addEventListener('click',runmewhenclicked);
    image2.addEventListener('click',runmewhenclicked);
    image3.addEventListener('click',runmewhenclicked);  

};  

function runmewhenclicked() {   

    var id = this.id;

    if(id == "image1")
    {
       document.getElementById("radioBtb1").checked = true;
    }
    else if(id == "image2")
    {
       document.getElementById("radioBtb2").checked = true;
    }
    else if(id == "image3")
    {
       document.getElementById("radioBtb3").checked = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: You've only provided half the code. Why didn't you do the other half?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed publish to soon!

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` now. Also, why the change in format? On your `onload` function you put the `{` on the same line as the `()`, but for the `runmewhenclicked` and `if`s, you put it on a seperate line.

Comment: @joeytje50 I ran it in my texteditor once more to test it for failures. And I pasted my test code back here... Sorry but it's fixed now!

Comment: Sorry. but I still having the same problem.
the radio buttons still unchecked when i click on the image