# set of Radio Buttons

Tags: html

Why if I put hyperlink around the images the previous solution didn't work? 
"I have a set of three radio buttons connected with a set of three images - i.e. {image1, radioBtn1}, {image2, radioBtn2}, {image3, radioBtn3}.

I'm trying to do the following: 
   when I click on one image, the radio button connected to this image gets checked' automatically (for example: when I click on image3, radioBtn3 will be checked)"

Comment: I don't really understand the question.. do you have any code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370007/set-of-radio-buttons-in-javascript/21370045?noredirect=1#comment32226840_21370045

Answer (score 1):

Add event listeners to each of the images telling the corresponding button to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `label` element to group the radio `input` and the `img`:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/dwpr4/)**

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="mode" value="create" />
    <img src="your_image.jpg" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example...[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/W486E/)

```
<section>
  <img src="/" class="radio-img" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="/" class="radio-img" alt="Image 2">
  <img src="/" class="radio-img" alt="Image 3">

  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
</section>

$('.radio-img').click(function() {
  $('input[name="radio"]').eq($(this).index()).trigger('click');
});
```

...but of course for this you must use jQuery.

To include jQuery library in your document, insert below code in the `<head>` section

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```